# How to automatically create indexes for Cloud Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Collection of `Lists` in which I store a bunch of documents. Each document contains a few details and a Collection of `users`. I store the users within the `users` Collection using the uid as a key and a boolean as a value. This means that only those users will be able to read that particular list. This is my database structure.

[image]
In my code I use this query:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference listsRef = rootRef.collection("Lists");
Query query = listsRef.orderBy("date").whereEqualTo("users."+uid, true);
```

And I get the following error:

```
FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: ...
```

If I go to the Console to create the required index, everything works fine. But is there a possibility to create the indexes automatically, because I cannot create manually an index for each user that joins my app. Is there a problem if I have a few sorting indexes for each user?

Is there another workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Cloud Firestore automatically creates indexes on individual fields of your documents. Complex indexes that span multiple fields can (currently) only be created manually in the Firebase console.

Also note that not all queries need a unique index, as Firestore may be able to [merge indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#taking_advantage_of_index_merging) (especially) for more complex queries. This can drastically reduce the number of unique indexes you need.

If you find that you need to create indexes programmatically, you typically should consider augmenting your data structure to allow a reverse lookup. For example, in your scenario, I'd add a `userLists` collection where you keep the lists for each user.

Comment: I understand now. I'll create a collection of lists under each user. Thank you Frank!

Comment: would refactoring lists.users to array and storing there ids of users be less optimal? You can than query it with array-contains and modify with atomic modification methods.

Comment: The `array-contains` operator was added well after this answer was written. It may indeed provide a better solution for this problem nowadays.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen do you have any material on using `array-contains` for this?